# Python Numpy 2D Array Number of Rows For Empty Matrix is Still 1

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Say I have a matrices A, B, and C.  When I initialize the matrices to

```
A = np.array([[]])
B = np.array([[1,2,3]])
C = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

Then

```
B.shape[0]
C.shape[0]
```

give 1 and 2, respectively (as expected), but

```
A.shape[0]
```

gives 1, just like B.shape[0].

What is the simplest way to get the number of rows of a given matrix, but still ensure that an empty matrix like A gives a value of zero.

After searching stack overflow for awhile, I couldn't find an answer, so I'm posting my own below, but if you can come up with a cleaner, more general answer, I'll accept your answer instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could qualify the `shape[0]` by the test of whether `size` is 0 or not.

```
In [121]: A.shape[0]*(A.size>0)
Out[121]: 0
In [122]: B.shape[0]*(B.size>0)
Out[122]: 1
In [123]: C.shape[0]*(C.size>0)
Out[123]: 2
```

or test the number of columns

```
In [125]: A.shape[0]*(A.shape[1]>0)
Out[125]: 0
```

What's distinctive about `A` is the number of columns, the 2nd dimension.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = np.array([[]])
```

That's a 1-by-0 array. You seem to want a 0-by-3 array. Such an array is almost completely useless, but if you really want one, you can make one:

```
A = np.zeros([0, 3])
```

Then you'll have `A.shape[0] == 0`.

Comment: Thanks.  That doesn't solve my problem, since I'm pulling in the array from a csv, which may potentially be blank.  Your answer might be helpful to someone else though.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
A.size/(len(A[0]) or 1)
B.size/(len(B[0]) or 1)
C.size/(len(C[0]) or 1)
```

yields 0, 1, and 2, respectively.